# jqueryui Accordion dynamic content behavior

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-ui-accordion

Edited to update to append to id and added the .accordion code.

I am using Jqueryui and building a dynamic list of accordions.  When clicked, the content is a php page with a unique marker. Below is part of the javascript that's creating the series of accordions: (note carriage returns added for readability below)

```
$('<h3 style="background:black;color:white;padding:2px;">
<a hidden href="subpage.php?crs='+val.idrepro+'"></a>
<div style="display:table-cell;padding-right:12px;vertical-align:middle;">
<p class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="zoom:2;margin:0;" title="'+val.idrepro+'"></p>
</div></h3>
<div>Loading... Please wait.</div>').appendTo('#accord');
```

where val.idrepro is different for each of about a hundred accordion titles.

```
$( "#accord" ).accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active : false,
    icons: null,
    heightStyle: "content",
    activate: function (e, ui) {
      $url = $(ui.newHeader[0]).children('a').attr('href');
  $.get($url, function (data) {
     $(ui.newHeader[0]).next().html(data);
      });
    }
 });
```

The problem I am having is that on first click of an accordion, all the buttons on the subpage work fine, but once more than one accordion option has ever been loaded, the buttons stop working, or rather the number of times that specific accordion title is opened and closed since load determines how many times you have to click the button in order for something to happen.

I have buttons that launch modal forms.  If more than one accordion had been cycled through, you could have to click the button for the modal 2,3,4 etc times in order to pop up the modal.

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to append an item to a class. A class selector select all items that have that class you must use the ID instead.

Comment: Hey Alvaro, I changed to .appendTo('#accord');  but it still does not work

Comment: It worked? You need an ID by element to access it and append the data.

Comment: That didn't work. I added to the post the code for calling the accordion widget.

Answer (score 0):

Okay figured it out.  My child php page had header information that was calling the jqueryui script again.  Removing the header data fixed the issue.  The page was originally designed to be loaded in a separate window and it didn't occur to me that this would cause a conflict when called by the accordion.

I removed all the code that was redundant to the parent.  Code removed:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO8859-15" />
<title><?echo($repname = $repsetupa['name']);?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.css" />
<style>
.ui-controlgroup-vertical {width: 150px;}
.ui-controlgroup.ui-controlgroup-vertical > button.ui-button,
.ui-controlgroup.ui-controlgroup-vertical > .ui-controlgroup-label {text-align: center;}
#car-type-button {width: 120px;}
.ui-controlgroup-horizontal .ui-spinner-input {width: 20px;}
.ui-tooltip, .arrow:after {background: black;border: 2px solid white;}
.ui-tooltip {padding: 10px 20px;color: white;border-radius: 20px;
    font: bold 14px "Helvetica Neue", Sans-Serif;text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px black;
}
.arrow {width:70px;height:16px;overflow:hidden;position: absolute;
    left: 50%;margin-left: -35px;bottom: -16px;
}
.arrow.top {top: -16px;bottom: auto;}
.arrow.left {left: 20%;}
.arrow:after {content: "";position: absolute;left: 20px;top: -20px;width: 25px;
    height: 25px;box-shadow: 6px 5px 9px -9px black;-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
.arrow.top:after {bottom: -20px;top: auto;}
.overflow {height:200px;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;}
.custom-combobox{position: relative;display: inline-block;}
.custom-combobox-toggle{position: absolute;top: 0;bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;padding: 0;}
.custom-combobox-input{margin: 0;padding: 5px 10px;}
.ui-autocomplete{overflow-y:scroll;height:200px;overflow-x:hidden;}
</style>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/jPages.js"></script>
```